Input values of Row subject Shouldn't intereact with each other
enter image description here
I recommend running the code to observe the issue. When you examine the form, you'll notice that the values entered in the second row (specifically, the course marks) are unintentionally affecting the grade calculation in the first row. This interaction is unexpected and indicates a problem with the way the form is handling inputs across different rows. Could you help me identify the cause of this issue and suggest a solution to ensure that the values in each row are processed independently, without interfering with other rows?


function generateEndYear() {
  const startYear = document.getElementById("start-year").value;
  const endYear = parseInt(startYear) + 4;
  document.getElementById("end-year").value = endYear;
}

function restrictToDigits(event) {
  const char = String.fromCharCode(event.which);
  if (!/^\d$/.test(char)) {
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

function restrictToAlphabets(event) {
  const char = String.fromCharCode(event.which);
  if (!/^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test(char)) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}

function validateCourseCode(input) {
  const value = input.value;
  if (value.length > 9) {
    input.value = value.slice(0, 9);
  }
}

function validateMarks(input) {
  const value = input.value;
  if (value.length > 2) {
    input.value = value.slice(0, 2);
  }
}

function calculateGrade(marks) {
  let grade = "";
  const gradeInput = document.getElementById("grade");
  marks = parseInt(marks);

  if (!isNaN(marks)) {
    if (marks >= 90 && marks <= 100) {
      grade = "A";
    } else if (marks >= 80 && marks < 90) {
      grade = "B";
    } else if (marks >= 70 && marks < 80) {
      grade = "C";
    } else if (marks >= 60 && marks < 70) {
      grade = "D";
    } else if (marks >= 0 && marks < 60) {
      grade = "F";
    } else {
      grade = "Invalid marks";
    }
  }

  gradeInput.value = grade;
}

function validatePhone(input) {
  const value = input.value;
  if (value.length > 11) {
    input.value = value.slice(0, 11);
  }
}

const subjectList = document.getElementById("subject-list");
const deleteButton = document.getElementById("minusButton");
if (subjectList.children.length === 1) {
  deleteButton.classList.add("hidden");
}

function duplicateRow() {
  const elementToDuplicate = subjectList.firstElementChild;
  const clone = elementToDuplicate.cloneNode(true);
  subjectList.appendChild(clone);
  updateDeleteButtonVisibility();
}

function deleteDuplicatedRow() {
  const lastChild = subjectList.lastElementChild;
  if (lastChild) {
    subjectList.removeChild(lastChild);
  }
  updateDeleteButtonVisibility();
}

function updateDeleteButtonVisibility() {
  const deleteButton = document.getElementById("minusButton");
  if (subjectList.children.length === 1) {
    deleteButton.classList.add("hidden");
  } else {
    deleteButton.classList.remove("hidden");
  }
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.6.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-Kc323vGBEqzTmouAECnVceyQqyqdsSiqLQISBL29aUW4U/M7pSPA/gEUZQqv1cwx4OnYxTxve5UMg5GT6L4JJg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
  />
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Transcript</h1>
  </header>

  <section>
    <form action="" method="post">
      <fieldset id="personalSet">
        <legend class="personal-legend">Personal Information</legend>

        <label for="fname">First Name</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" name="fname" required autocomplete="on" onkeypress="return restrictToAlphabets(event)" />

        <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" name="lname" required autocomplete="on" onkeypress="return restrictToAlphabets(event)" />

        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required autocomplete="on" placeholder="E-mail" />

        <label for="telephone">Phone No.</label>
        <input type="tel" name="telephone" id="telephone" required autocomplete="on" placeholder="Phone No." oninput="validatePhone(this)" onkeypress="return restrictToDigits(event)" />

        <label for="bname">Birth Date</label>
        <input type="date" name="bdate" required />

        <label for="address">Address</label>
        <input type="text" name="address" placeholder="1234 Main St, Apt 101" autocomplete="on" />

        <label for="program">Programs</label>
        <select name="program" id="program">
          <option value="BS.IT">BS.IT</option>
          <option value="BS.ED">BS.ED</option>
          <option value="BS.PHY">BS.PHY</option>
          <option value="BS.ENG">BS.ENG</option>
        </select>

        <label for="semester">Semester</label>
        <select name="semester" id="semester">
          <option value="1st">1st</option>
          <option value="2nd">2nd</option>
          <option value="3rd">3rd</option>
          <option value="4th">4th</option>
          <option value="5th">5th</option>
          <option value="6th">6th</option>
          <option value="7th">7th</option>
          <option value="8th">8th</option>
        </select>

        <label for="start-year">Academic Year</label>
        <input type="number" id="start-year" name="start-year" placeholder="2021" min="1900" max="2100" oninput="generateEndYear()" /> -
        <input type="number" id="end-year" name="end-year" readonly disabled />
      </fieldset>

      <fieldset id="courseSet">
        <legend class="course-legend">Course Information</legend>
        <div id="subject-list">
          <div id="subject-row">
            <label for="c-code">Course Code</label>
            <input type="text" id="c-code" name="c-code" pattern="\d{4}" placeholder="ICTC-101" required oninput="validateCourseCode(this)" />
            <span class="error">Please enter exactly 5 digits.</span>

            <label for="c-name">Course Name</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Course Name" name="c-name" required autocomplete="on" />

            <label for="c-hours">Course Marks</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Course Marks" name="c-marks" required autocomplete="on" oninput="validateMarks(this); calculateGrade(this.value);" onkeypress="return restrictToDigits(event)" />

            <label for="grade">Grade</label>
            <input type="text" id="grade" name="grade" required disabled />

            <label for="c-hours">Course Hours</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Course Hours" name="c-hours" required autocomplete="on" onkeypress="return restrictToDigits(event)" />

            <label for="instructor-name">Instructor Name</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Instructor Name" name="instructor-name" required autocomplete="on" onkeypress="return restrictToAlphabets(event)" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </fieldset>

      <div class="plus-icon">
        <button type="button" id="plusButton" onclick="duplicateRow()">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-plus"></i>
          </button>
      </div>

      <div class="minus-icon">
        <button type="button" id="minusButton" onclick="deleteDuplicatedRow()">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-minus"></i>
          </button>
      </div>

      <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
  </section>
</body>

</html>



I want that each row's value should react only with their elements.

Should there re multiple sections of "Course Information"? Your code only has one.

const gradeInput = document.getElementById("grade"); Element IDs must be unique; if there are duplicates, it will always retrieve the first one.

Is this a JS problem, a PHP problem, or any HTML problem?
